# Canadian Duty and Taxes

Tags: taxes

I am trying to find a way to add $6.95 to orders shipping to Canada (we're in the US.) The $6.95 amount represents prepaid duties. If the site does not prepay the duties, the cost of the duties can triple, and the customer may refuse the shipment.

I've seen add-ons for entire packages like Zonos and Alavera, but I only need this one particular prepaid duty.

Thank you

Jeff

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-extra-fee/

Comment: what are the shipping methods you currently use? also, are you keen to do this with Magento out of the box features or do you have in mind to add some custom codes?

Comment: I use USPS media mail exclusively. I'd rather do this with out of the box features if possible. It's only for Canadian customers, which would be about 20 customers in all.